# webforms: how to remove DOM element if item is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, webforms

I have a aproblem with a horizontal navigation I am using in a small asp.net project.
The nav contains a Login, Profile and Logout anchor, which are displayed if you are logged in, or not.

I am realizing this behaviour by setting .Visible attribute in Code Behind.

Now i want to add a pipe after every element as a "divider". This must not be a part of the actual list item itself because it would screw over the a:hover effect.

But even if the element is *not* in the DOM tree, die pipe-divider is shown.
which looks like

> Login | | |

I have tried solving it with

```
if ($("li.nav-item").length == 0) {
            $('span.divider').remove();
        }
        if ($("li.nav-item").length > 0 && $("li.nav-item").is(':visible')) {
            $('<span class="divider"> | </span>').appendTo('li.nav-item');
        }
```

but this doesnt work. How can I solve this?

Kind regards.

/edit: html markup (edited IDs)

```
<ul id="navigation">
                <li class="nav-item"><asp:HyperLink ID="link1" runat ="server" Text="LoremIpsum"      NavigateUrl="#" /></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><asp:LinkButton ID="LoremIpsum" runat ="server" Text="LoremIpsum" PostBackUrl="~/#.aspx"  /></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><asp:HyperLink ID="link2" runat="server"  Text="LoremIpsum" NavigateUrl="#.aspx"/></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><asp:HyperLink ID="linkLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" NavigateUrl="~/login.aspx"/></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><asp:HyperLink ID="linkProfile" runat="server" Text="Profile" NavigateUrl="~/profile.aspx" Visible="false"/></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><asp:HyperLink ID="linkLogout" runat="server" Text="Logout" NavigateUrl="~/logout.aspx" Visible="false"/></li>
                <li><asp:HyperLink ID="LoremIpsum" runat="server" Text="LoremIpsum" NavigateUrl="~/nutzungsbedingungen.aspx"/></li>
                </ul>


if (Session["svar_loggedin"] != null)
    {
        linkLogin.Visible = false;
        linkProfile.Visible = true;
        linkLogout.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        linkLogin.Visible = true;
        linkProfile.Visible = false;
        linkLogout.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use borders? They natively hide for hidden elements, don't need javascript, and they don't have the nasty effect of meaningless layout elements.

Comment: because the pipes are explicitly requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this js instead:

```
$.each($("li.nav-item").children("a").filter(":visible"), function (e) {
    $('<span class="divider"> | </span>').appendTo($(this));
});
```

EDIT:

Either use css instead of Visible property:

```
linkLogin.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none")
```

or alt. iterate through the controls, check if visible == true, if so add the span-markup to the Text-attribute

Comment: the filter with visible doesnt work. Because the elements visibility is set in codebehind via the asp.net .visible property it isn't available in the DOM tree.
Nontheless, the pipes are added.

Comment: I've decided to go with the attributes. Now I need to come up with a jQuery snippet to remove the pipes if the element becomes invisible.

Which attribute do I need to remove to make an item invisible?

Comment: Can a visible element become invisible without a full page load? If not, then above code should work.

Comment: it kind of works ... I still have the problem with the triple pipes.

Comment: I guess I found the root of my issues.
In Codebehind I am dealing with the asp:hyperlink controls and hide them. The corresponding list item is still visible. Thats why the pipes are rendered. So I need to finde a li.nav-item which child(?) is visible

Comment: Oh, of course... Try the updated answer if you haven't figured it out already :)

Comment: marking your answer as correct, although we took slightly different approaches. Both do work.

Answer (score 2):

```
  $(function () {
        var elements = $('li.nav-item > a').filter(':visible');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length - 1; i++) {
            elements.eq(i).append($('<span class="divider"> | </span>'));
        }

    });
```

in my case this did the trick. I was not realising that my Code Behind was altering the asp:Hyperlink controls and not the list items.

I changed my Jquery Snippet accordingly to relate to all anchors which are a child of list-items with the class 'nav-item'.

thank you all for bringing me back on track!

Comment: i was right, if you had posted client html-markup, you will receive answer more quickly.